# Creating custom getters and setters dynamically under STI in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I am relatively new to meta programming and I am trying to define getters and setters in children models under a single table inheritance, like so:

```
# app/models/player.rb
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :equipments

  protected
  # Define getters for setters for individual sports
  def attr_equipments(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      define_singleton_method(attribute) do
        self.equipments[attribute.to_sym]
      end

      define_singleton_method("#{attribute}=") do |value|
        self.equipments[attribute.to_sym] = value
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/models/baseball_player.rb
class BaseballPlayer < Player
  after_initialize do
    attr_equipments :bat, :glove
  end
end
```

On a higher layer I would like to do something like this:

```
# app/controllers/baseball_players_controller.rb
class BaseballPlayersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @baseball_player = BaseballPlayer
  end
end

# app/views/baseball_players/new.html.haml
=form_for(@baseball_player) do |f|
  =f.text_field :bat
  =f.text_field :glove
  =f.submit
```

But with the example above I cannot get or set the attributes even from the console.

```
> p = BaseballPlayer.new
> p.bat
> # returns NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

> p = BaseballPlayer.new
> p.bat = "Awesome bat"
> # returns ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
```

Could someone help me find the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like whatever job_arguments is is nil...

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue myself..

For future references, this part needed to be store as serialize does not automatically define any accessors.

```
# app/models/player.rb
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  # serialize :equipments -> does not create a setter or getter needed
  store :equipments
```

I also encountered an error in create method in the controller:

```
def create
  @alarm = BaseballPlayer.new(alarm_params)
  # Error: undefined attribute 'bat'
```

which was solved by:

```
def create
  @alarm = BaseballPlayer.new
  @alarm.assign_attributes(alarm_params)
```